# Jmeter and JSF issue javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: jmeter

I have create the Jmeter script for my JSF application by following the below steps:

1. Added HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder to the work bench and added URL Patterns to include and also given the global port in my browser.
2. Created Test plan and Thread Group, as shown in the following image
   [screenshot _a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffL4H.png)
3. As i was using JSF application, so i have to handle the ViewState. For this i used Regular Expression Extractor as shown in the following image [screenshot_b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WMJi.png)
4. And started the script, it was running and viewstate id also passing to next request. this time im getting the below error:

---

```
18:09:29,757 INFO  [com.boeing.Wsrd.web.util.WsrdViewExpiredExceptionHandler] (ajp-/10.105.5.111:8109-7) APPLICATION ERROR!!!!
18:09:29,757 ERROR [com.boeing.Wsrd.web.util.WsrdViewExpiredExceptionHandler] (ajp-/10.105.5.111:8109-7) Application exception from handler: javax.faces.FacesException: Unexpected error restoring state for component with id j_idt132.  Cause: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:387) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1652) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:367) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:577) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:142) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:301) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.richfaces.application.GlobalResourcesViewHandler.restoreView(GlobalResourcesViewHandler.java:179) [richfaces-core-4.5.1.Final.jar:4.5.1.Final]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.boeing.Wsrd.web.filter.ClearCache.doFilter(Unknown Source) [classes:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.boeing.ccl.auth.web.UserFilter.doFilter(UserFilter.java:68) [ccl-audit-lib-1.6.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.boeing.Wsrd.web.filter.WsrdRoles.actionForSessionBems(Unknown Source) [classes:]
        at com.boeing.Wsrd.web.filter.WsrdRoles.getUserDetails(Unknown Source) [classes:]
        at com.boeing.Wsrd.web.filter.WsrdRoles.doFilter(Unknown Source) [classes:]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Very broad problem statement. Error message is not helpful as well. Have you tried troubleshooting yourself and narrowing down the real issue.

Comment: When i'm running the Jmeter script for my application getting the below error,